# Inserting a line break in an attribute value of a custom component

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, html

Hi Iam facing a error for this below code.

```
</apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Web Time Entry" rendered="{!order.Type=='Web Timesheet'}" columns="1">
            <apex:actionRegion >                    
                <table style="width:50%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:right;width:35%;font-weight:bold;font-size:11px;color: #4a4a56;padding-right: 2px;">
                         Line 246<--<c:helpicon helpText="Hours per Day: Employee enters total number of hours for each day.<br/>In and Out times per day: Associate enters Start and End time along with any Break Start and End Times. Some states require time to be recorded as Ins and Outs."/>
                            How do you want associates to enter time?</td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 10px;"><apex:inputField value="{!order.Associates_to_enter_time__c}" id="aelist" >                                  
                            </apex:inputField>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                    
            </apex:actionRegion>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="When do you want associates to receive email reminders?" rendered="{!order.Type=='Web Timesheet'}" columns="1">
                <apex:actionRegion >                    `
```

the error message is

> Missing required attribute helpText in `<c:helpicon>` in OONewClientOAFS2 at line 246 column 33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your outputText, set `escape="false"`

**OR** change the style of your output field (whatever it is) to something like:

```
<apex:outputText value="Help Text" style="white-space:pre;" />
```

**OR**

Remove the literal html `<br/>` with this: `&#13;` in the string and change to a regular span or div.

```
<div>{!yourHelpText}</div>
```

**OR** Don't remove anything, but switch to a regular div or span and set it's style to `white-space:pre;`:

```
<div style="white-space:pre;">{!yourHelpText}</div>
```

Comment: Using `escape="false"` seems extremely unwise in a reusable component like `<c:helpicon>`.

Comment: Caspar , I tried replacing  &#13 ; instead of <br/>  now it throws error as

Comment: "Illegal group reference" at line 0

Comment: Try the other options

Comment: @SamuelRobert - I noticed that you wrote &#13 ; instead of &#13; - I'm not totally sure about this, but I'd say an HTML entity should not have a space before the semicolon.

Comment: No Caspar I wrote it exactly the same without space between &#13;

Comment: If you are going to use that technique (I'm guessing you are using a substitute function, use `\n` or `\r\n` rather than &#13;.

Comment: Hey, just wondering, what was your final technique?